# Unable to generate json data using xsl

Tags: json, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have to generate json data using xslt but I am unable to add strings in another string

Json Data I want

```
{
 "quoteListInfo" : [ 
  {
     "quote" : {
     "Name" : "MyTest", 
     "BillingCity" : "Matheran"
  },

   "productModel" : [
    {
     "Product_SKU" : "AD-003",
     "Product_Title" : "Adidas Shoes",
     "Product_Quantity" : "10"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to add name and billing city inside quote.
It gives me error if I run below code.
Array is working perfect but I am unable to add String inside string

xsl I have written

```
  <xsl:output method="sdml:org.selfhtml.xslt.JSONEmitter"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">   
    <object>
        <array key="quoteListInfo">
            <object>        
                <string key="quote">
                    <object>
                               <string key="Name">Test</string>
                               <string key="BillingCity">Mumbai</string>
                    </object> 
                </string>   
                <array key="productModel">
                    <object>
                        <string key="Product_SKU">AD-003</string>
                        <string key="Product_Title">Reebok</string>
                        <string key="Product_Quantity">10</string>
                    </object>
                </array>        
            </object>
        </array>  
    </object>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
  <xsl:template match="/">   
    <object>
        <array key="quoteListInfo">
            <object key="quote">        
                               <string key="Name">Test</string>
                               <string key="BillingCity">Mumbai</string>
            </object> 

                <array key="productModel">
                    <object>
                        <string key="Product_SKU">AD-003</string>
                        <string key="Product_Title">Reebok</string>
                        <string key="Product_Quantity">10</string>
                    </object>
                </array>        
        </array>  
    </object>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess String cannot have another string in it. As per documentation of sdhtml.

array
Defines a JSON array, may contain any other element, the order of the elements defines the order in which they appear inside the array.

object
Defines a JSON object, may contain any other element. Each subelement must have the key attribute set that defines the name of the object property for which the element will be the value. Note that the key attribute must not be set for elements that are not subelements of object.

**string
Defines a JSON string. Must contain the literal string contents.**

number
Defines a JSON number. Must contain the literal number.

true
Defines the JSON boolean value true. Must be empty.

false
Defines the JSON boolean value false. Must be empty.

null
Defines the JSON special value null. Must be empty.

Please refer the below link
http://christian-seiler.de/projekte/xslt-json/